# Sum tow byte variable that casting to int

Tags: c#

I explicit cast my variable to in and then use plus operator but still return 44 I want to know why this happen i explicit casting my variable to int.

```
byte b = 100;
b = (byte)(b +200);
```

Why use this my result is 255?

```
byte b = 100;
b = (byte)(b + 155);
```

Comment: You get an overflow. the byte-value of 300-256 = 44

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's split this up:

```
byte b = 100;
int tmp = (int) b + (int) 200;
b = (byte) b;
```

Now `tmp` will have a value of 300... but that isn't representable as a `byte`. When you cast it to `byte` (in an unchecked context) it will end up as 44.

The relevant bit of the C# 5 specification, section 6.2.1:

> The explicit numeric conversions possibly lose information or possibly cause exceptions to be thrown. An explicit numeric conversion is processed as follows:
>
> - For a conversion from an integral type to another integral type, the processing depends on the overflow checking context (§7.6.12) in which the conversion takes place:
>
>   - In a checked context, the conversion succeeds if the value of the source operand is within the range of the destination type, but throws a System.OverflowException if the value of the source operand is outside the range of the destination type.
>   - In an unchecked context, the conversion always succeeds, and proceeds as follows.
>
>     - If the source type is larger than the destination type, then the source value is truncated by discarding its “extra” most significant bits. The result is then treated as a value of the destination type.

That last bullet is exactly what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of "100 + 200" is 300. 300 can't fit into a byte (which you cast it to), so the higher bits are thrown away - leaving you with 44.

What did you even expect to happen?